# QGIS -Z coordinate

Tags: qgis

QGIS 3.6.1,
is it possible to add Z coordination to the vertex of line shapefile using Vertex editor? I can add value of 6, but it is not possible to add 6,2.

Comment: did you try with a "." (dot) like in 6.2 also ?

Comment: Yes, it returns 62..

Comment: I tested it with 3.6.0 and 2.18.28 on the same layer. You can add decimal Z value with 2.18 but not with 3.6. it look like a bug with QGIS 3

Comment: What locale do you have in Option-General?

Comment: Yes, its true, i tested 2.18.14 and it works. 
I have a czech locale, i tested it with default and it does not work also

Comment: I was able to add a decimal Z value to a shapefile in EPSG:4326 in QGIS 3.6.1.